# How to compute readable format ratio from image dimensions

Tags: php, math

I would like to calculate a readable format ratio (such as 3:4 or 2:3) from a given set of dimensions (such as 40x60).

Probably very basic maths, but i can't wrap my head around it.

Anyone know how this can be done in PHP?

```
function computeReadableRatio($x, $y){
   // ???
}
```

Comment: You just need to reduce the fraction to lowest terms? Like you did when you were learning fractions in 2nd grade?

Comment: Does "greatest common divisor" ring a bell? Use that, and show us your code if you run into trouble.

Comment: Guys, thanks for pushing me. I know i deserve it, its super basic stuff. But i still needed that input.

Comment: No, that is simple abuse, not 'pushing'.  You'd be justified in flagging them or at least the first one.  Your question is perfectly fine.

Comment: After consideration - no flagging. Perhaps i just never went to 2nd grade :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gmp_gcd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-gcd.php) will give you the largest number that divides both inputs.  Then you can divide through by the result to get your reduced ratio.

```
<?php

function computeReadableRatio($x, $y){
   $d = gmp_gcd($x, $y);
   $xnew = gmp_div($x, $d);
   $ynew = gmp_div($y, $d);

    echo gmp_strval($d) . ' ' . gmp_strval($xnew) . ' ' . gmp_strval($ynew);

}

computeReadableRatio(40, 60);
?>
```

Comment: Oh, i got in too early. Basically using this function, feeding it with $x=40 and $y=60, i get back this: $xnew=0.34782608695652 $ynew=0.52173913043478 - i guess i missed something important?

Comment: @CummanderCheckov Ok see the above, it works and produces `20 2 3` on ideone.  Turns out there's some extra things you have to do with the GMP library.

Answer (score 2):

Since you often won't get numbers which *exactly* match the desired ratio, you could do a [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of their quotient. Truncating that continued fraction can give you a [best rational approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations). The point where you truncate is up to you, balancing small numbers against exactness of the result.